# MySQL - referring back to previous row to add calculated column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm new to MySQL and I'm having trouble with the problem below;

Let's call this table `runners_table`

```
+---------+-----------+
| race_id | runner_id | 
+---------+-----------+
|    10   |  A        |   
|    10   |  E        | 
|    10   |  V        | 
|    23   |  G        | 
|    23   |  J        |  
|    23   |  A        | 
|    67   |  E        | 
|    67   |  G        | 
|    67   |  X        | 
+---------+-----------+
```

And I want to add a new column like this;

```
+---------+-----------+--------------+
| race_id | runner_id | prev_race_id | 
+---------+-----------+--------------+
|    10   |  A        | -            |
|    10   |  E        | -            |
|    10   |  V        | -            |
|    23   |  G        | -            | 
|    23   |  J        | -            | 
|    23   |  A        | 10           | 
|    67   |  E        | 10           |
|    67   |  G        | 23           | 
|    67   |  X        | -            | 
+---------+-----------+--------------+
```

Where `prev_race_id` looks back and gets the previous `race_id` for the same `runner_id`.

To illustrate;
What I'd like to do is, say a runner took part in 6 races out of 10 races that year, in the row relating to his 5th race I want to know the race_id of his 4th race.

I guess I could make a new table for every runner that was a record of the races they took part in, but this would stretch to hundreds of tables... there must be a better way.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: unless you want to worry about always patching your data, come up with an ingenious query

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as a previous row unless you have a column containing ordering information.  Examples are the numeric value of the race, an auto increment id, or creation date.

Comment: the problem that @GordonLinoff mentions, specificly is: imagine in your 3 columns table as you present it here, you insert a new row `10 J -`. that would invalidate your current state.

Comment: @GordonLinoff (& Cowan6891) The 3-column table in the question is a valid way to record the info. (But maybe you are just pointing out that the ordering info isn't in the 2-column table?)

Comment: @hoijui & (Cowan6891) The current state must always be set to describe the current situation. Just inserting that row leaves the table in an invalid state. It is an update error. It has nothing to do with what rows are supposed to be in the table, ie the table design. Granted, this table design means that if you add a new race you have to tediously find or redundantly remember a person's most recent race. (Also I doubt GordonLinoff's comment is re your problem since another example of ordering information is a linked list like the 3-column table but with just race_id & prev_race_id.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is using a correlated subquery.  Assuming `race_id` is in numerical order:

```
select r.*,
       (select r2.race_id
        from runners_table r2
        where r2.race_id < r.race_id and r2.runner_id = r.runner_id
        order by r2.race_id desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_race_id
from runners_table r;
```

If some other column determines the previous record, then the `where` and `order by` would change.

Comment: This adds a column with the previous race_id but I'm trying to get the previous race_id featuring that runner.

Comment: @Cowan6891 . . . Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can create 3 tables, one for race, one for runner and one for the relationship between them. Since you stored the date of every race you can get the previus one easily.

```
   CREATE TABLE Race(
         race_id INT,
         data VARCHAR(100)
       );

   CREATE TABLE Runner(
         runner_id INT,
         data VARCHAR(100)
       );

   CREATE TABLE Race_Runner(
         race_id INT,
         runner_id INT,
         fecha DATETIME
       );
```

---

If you want to know the previous race date for a specific runner, try this query:

---

```
select race_id 
from Race_Runner 
where fecha <> (select max(fecha) from Race_Runner) 
and runner_id = ? -- the runner you want
order by fecha desc 
limit 1
```

---

The following query returns the value of each runner with the previous race date:

---

```
select runner_id, 
LAG(fecha) over (partition by runner_id order by fecha desc) 
as previous_date_race
from Race_Runner
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit green with MySQL, what would the query look like that would add the column and grab the previous race_id for that runner?

Comment: `select race_id 
from Race_Runner 
where fecha <> (select max(fecha) from Race_Runner) 
order by fecha desc
limit 1 `

Comment: Ok got this working now.  It gets the race_id for the most recent race when fed a runner_id manually.  It's not what I need though.  I've amended the original question now.

Comment: I would need to simulate the LAG function as I'm just using MySQL.  Got a solution now from @GordonLinoff.  Thanks for your help.